Unable to use UART and Bluetooth in RPi3 with audio output simulatneously
I am using Rpi 3b+ and I am trying to use the Bluetooth and UART simultaneously.
with ls -l /dev:
Serial 0 - ttyAMA0
Serial 1 - ttyS0

I had to use the UART (for reading coordinates in GPS) and meanwhile connect bluetooth and output the audio from the audio jack.

Things I did:
sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyS0.service
sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyS0.service


in config.txt:
enable_uart = 1
dtoverlay=miniuart-bt
core_frequency=250


in cmdline.txt:
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 



My GPS code :
import serial
import time
import string
import pynmea2

while True:
    port="/dev/ttyAMA0"
    ser=serial.Serial(port, baudrate=9600, timeout=0.5)
    dataout = pynmea2.NMEAStreamReader()
    newdata=ser.readline()

    if newdata[0:6] == "$GPRMC":
        newmsg=pynmea2.parse(newdata)
        lat=newmsg.latitude
        lng=newmsg.longitude
        gps = "Latitude=" + str(lat) + "and Longitude=" + str(lng)
        print(gps)

The GPS data is coming, the bluetooth getting connected to phone but the audio is not okay. It is playing sometimes and then breaking.
Can I in any way swap the functionalities, so ttyAMA0 would be for bluetooth and ttyA0 would be for GPS communication?
AFTER REVERTING:
I got a new SD card, enabled only the serial intarface.

ls -l /dev:
Serial 0 - ttyS0
Serial 1 - ttyAMA0

UART and Bluetooth works fine.

Reverting changes in old SD card:

I removed the dtoverlay=miniuart-bt and enable_uart = 1 again turned on serial through sudo raspi-config
But ls -l /dev gives me only
Serial 1 - ttyAMA0

I am not able to find the /dev/serial0


You don't do yourself any favours by posting rubbish. ls -l /dev/serial* shows
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Apr 30 09:17 /dev/serial0 -> ttyS0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr 30 09:17 /dev/serial1 -> ttyAMA0 - nothing like your post. You appear to have disabled services which you also have to revert. I suggest you just use the new SD Card.

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 May 15 15:47 /dev/serial1 -> ttyAMA0
this is what i meant while running ls -l /dev/

If you didn't fiddle with things and enabled serial in raspi-config it should work using /dev/serial0 which will ALWAYS be the available serial port on GPIO 14/15.
What you claim to want is how it works if you don't break it.

I did the same but the gps data is not coming.

can in any way i can revert those changes. now it is not showing serial0. only serial 1 is showing

You claim to have "reverted" changes but provided no details. As it currently stands your question is unchanged so no one knows what you have. If it was me I would just restore from my backup.

I tested in a new sd card. just by enabling the serial and both uart and bluetooth are working fine. Now after reverting the changes in the old sd card it doesnot at all shows /dev/serial0. I have edited my question. please check
